# How to append columns of data using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file in this format:-

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
```

I need assistance to append the columns in a loop like this

```
1
5
9

2
6
10

...
```

Comment: Do you have 12 whitespace-separated columns in a file? Do you want to only get columns number 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10? Where are you going to append them?

Answer (score 2):

this line should work with dynamic rows and columns

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR][i]=$i}END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)print a[j][i]; print ""}}' file
```

it looks better in this format:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR][i]=$i}
    END{
            for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)
                    print a[j][i]
                print ""
            }
        }' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR][i]=$i}END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)print a[j][i]; print ""}}' file
1
5
9

2
6
10

3
7
11

4
8
12
```

Comment: Thanks Kent But I got this error:-                                       awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR][i]=$i}END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)print a[j][i]; print ""}}' file
 syntax error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                 >>> {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR][ <<< 
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 1.
 syntax error The source line is 1.

Comment: @user2262751 - you are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk and /usr/bin/awk on Solaris). On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk.

Comment: @EdMorton, I am using AIX and is /usr/bin/awk. How can you assist pls.

Comment: @user2262751 get a new awk. Download and install GNU awk from http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk.